# Bold citation call-outs

Tags: citing, bold

I would like to typeset some of the citation call-outs (not entries) in bold. Ideally, I would like to have something like "Studies of topic A [1, **2**, 4] are very important. Studies of topic B [**3**, **5**, 6] are also important." Moreover, in a different part of the document I would like to cite the same papers without their references being in bold: "We have seen above that both topics are important [2,3,4]."

Is this even possible?

Comment: Please tell us how LaTeX is supposed to "know" when (and when not) to render a numeric style citation call-out in bold. A general remark: I would assume that **bold**-faced citation callouts are supposed to be more important or relevant than their non-bold counterparts. If that's the case, **bold**-facing may be too subtle a signal for many readers. They may rather prefer you writing a sentence or two each time, to inform your readers what, specifically, is so important about a given bibliographic entry. Please also advise whether you employ a package such as `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: Dear @Mico I have been thinking about something like ``\cite{ref1,\textbf{ref2}, ref4}''. Bold-faced citations are not necessarily more important, they are coming from a follow-up literature study (as opposed to the non-bold-faced ones that are coming from the original literature study). The style file is free, so any solution is welcome.